# jQuery transitions don't finish

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I added some transitions to a image rollover:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.project').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('.description').stop().slideDown('fast');
    }, function(){
        $(this).children('.description').stop().slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

However sometimes the description box only slide halfway down, or even just 1 tenth of the length it should slide... the description box is 300 by 300px, and is supposed to slide into a 300x300px box...

This seems to happen if I hover over the .project very quickly, could the stop() be adding itself to the queue thus stopping things when it shouldn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `stop( true, true )` if you want the animation to be completed immediately or `stop( true, false )` if you don't want to complete the animation, just reverse it. The first true will clear the queue so the animation can start over. I'm not completely sure why it's going wrong and I apologize for not being able to give a more complete answer but right now I'm not in the position to look it up. You can read more about it here though: http://api.jquery.com/stop/, I've found the jQuery API usually pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

I created an example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gizmovation/TpqvT/

I am able to get the description box to appear partway by quickly mousing in and out of the project container.

This happens because `stop()` is halting the previous animation and then you are starting a new one. Passing `stop(true, true)` as mentioned in the other answer will make things look a little better.

Are you having trouble with the animation hanging completely? If so, modify the jsfiddle I created to better illustrate the issue and we can offer further assistance.