# Jquery fading, fades in and out with a single click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem, it's been doing it for weeks, I just can't fix it.

I have a few nested lists with hidden divs inside, and when one div is clicked the hidden div shows, BUT after showing one div, when I try to do the same to another div it shows and hides with a single click, it isn't supposed to do this.

the HTML is valid and so is the javascript, this is making me crazy.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amando96/TPZuu/

I have the exact same thing running locally and it doesn't work, but it's fine in Jsfiddle... is this a jquery bug or something I'm not at fault for?

I commented out all the other lines in the JS and css files just in case they were interfering, but is keeps doing it.

Comment: your jdfiddle works fine for me on the latest Chrome... it shows when I click and hides when I click again, no matter which one I click on

Comment: working just fine., I guess you have something else in your code, definitely it is different from this fiddle.

Comment: I have nothing else in my code. Well, I do, but I commented everything out in all my JS and CSS, so all in all the files are exactly like the ones in jsfiddle. I have no clue what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

By what you described, it's unlikely to be a bug in jQuery.

If it works in the fiddle but not your code, you most likely DO NOT have the exact same scenario. There's something else happening in your code that's not present in the fiddle. A few debugging pointers:

1. Set breakpoints in key points of the code
2. When breakpoint reached, check for selectors results
3. When breakpoint reached, check for DOM status (presence of elements, etc.)

Comment: Odds are it's the old classic, no ready function locally. JSFiddle adds this for you which is why it works there.

Comment: @SpaceBeers It could be, but we cannot assume that. See this other question from same OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768209/jquery-transitions-dont-finish OP uses the `$(document).ready()` construct there

Comment: It's all there, I've commented out everything so all files are exactly like the ones in the Jsfiddle, it just won't work.

Comment: I have also used completely different class and id names, it still won't work.